# Differentiability of piecewise functions for calculus proofs

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, piecewise-continuity

Hi I have been trying to understand piecewise functions and differentiability and I am quite confused about how some derivatives of piecewise functions are defined .for example if I have a function f(x)={2x:x$\le$2
The derivative of this function at x=2 is undefined as the limit from the right does not exist but is this function differentiable due to the existence of one sided derivatives?

Comment: The limit from the right need not exist, as the function is undefined on the right. Review the precise definition of a limit.

Comment: Yes but for differentiability at a point mustn't we consider the limit from both left and right

Comment: The derivative is a limit like any other. Review the precise definition of a limit.

Comment: OK but is the derivative at x=2 a one sided derivative as function is not defined for x$\ge$2

Comment: For the last time, the derivative is a limit like any other. It follows the same rules as all limits. Review the precise definition of a limit.